# wp_nav_menu not working properly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to convert html menu to WordPress menu but It does not work properly.my implements code are as blow:

**HTML Code**

```
  <!-- start navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url();?>">WpF <span>BGness</span></a>
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a> -->
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar_area">          
       <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom_nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>               
            </ul>
          </li>             
          <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog-archive.html">Blog</a></li>                    
        </ul> -->

        <?php 
        $args=array('theme_location'=>'primary');
        wp_nav_menu($args);
        ?>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End navbar -->
```

**Register menu** 
I have register a menu inside my **functions.php**.

```
add_theme_support('menus');
function awsome_menu_add()
{
      register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary'   => __( 'primary menu'),
            'secondary' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
            'responsive'=> __( 'Responsive Menu'),
            'footer'    => __( 'Footer Menu'),
        ) );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme','awsome_menu_add');
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: class are not attached here.Thats why menu not working.

Answer (score 0):

change your code with lowercase of your theme location.

from

```
$args=array('theme_location'=>'Primary');
```

to

```
$args=array('theme_location'=>'primary');
```

Comment: this is not an issue menu is display its in vertical

Comment: if you use proper case in code then selected menu item set from admin  will display at front end otherwise it will display all pages as menu item.

Comment: when I add sub menu that goes vertical